# Country restricted apps: how to find out where the app is available?

Tags: google-play-store

It is well known that some apps can only be downloaded in specific countries.

There are a lot of tutorials on the net that show how do bypass this restriction and download the app anyway.

However those tutorials require you to know in which country the app is available.

Is there are an automated way to find out in which country/countries an app is available (except from stupidly trying out each and every country)?

Comment: Why not downloading those apps from e.g. [ApkMirror](http://apkmirror.com), which shares only legitimate APK files (the same as the Play Store ones)? You'll just need the app's name, by doing so.

Comment: Googling for the app doesn't provide informations on where it is released?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman because a user may not willing be to trust any third party site to fetch the APK, no matter its reputation.

Comment: @esQmo: That works some times, but it is based on human intelligence and therefore can not be automated.

Comment: @Firelord Reasonable enough to deserve an upvote. Bravo.

Answer (score 3):

[42 matters](https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/availability) seems to provide this. I haven't checked out by signing in. It claims to provide this information

> Country Availability API for Android Apps
>
> Check in which countries an Android app is available on Google Play Store™.

**Source:** [Andrea, On Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-get-Android-application-details-from-Google-Play-Store-by-package-name)

Comment: It works. But their pricing is quite high. Nothing for a small developer or a private user.

Comment: Not really good due to prohibitive pricing (300$/mo). Free trial isn't a real trial, only dummy.