# Play Store -- Relevance of color of Icon with initial in it

Tags: google-play-store

I recently had an issue in trying to download an app for a Canadian product from Google play. Despite being in Canada, on a Canadian WiFi system or Canadian SIM Card on a Canadian carrier the download was refused because "This item is not available in your Country". I created a new account but had the same results, I used my wifes phone on her account, same result! I then remembered an old account I had, logged in with that and it worked. The only difference I could see with the new account on Google Play was the circle with my initial in it in the box "Search for apps & games" was blue in colour, all the other logins the circle was orange. What is the meaning of the circles colour?

Comment: The circle color is to an account property. If you don't have set a profile image as far as I know the color is just chosen on device side. If you are really interested why the could not be downloaded please post the Google Play Store link.

Comment: As per Robert's comment, the color is unrelated, it's randomly generated by Google. Your old account might have a country set to Canada, and/or also a payment method acceptable in Canada. The latter is usually important to unlock country-restricted apps.

Comment: @AndrewT. That a payment method has influence of the possibility to download of a free app is something I can not confirm. I have downloader accounts that never had a payment option and I can switch them to any country. The only possibility where a country restriction may get rely on a certain payment method is if it is more  a carrier than a country restriction. Baz: regarding country restricted apps please check out this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161863/2241

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all the accounts I use have been created in Canada, the payment methods are on Canadian Credit cards. As far as I can see all other information on the accounts is the same except for the language selection. One account has English (Canada), this one failed the download. The others had English(United States) one failed, the other was successful! The app in Play Store is Bluelink Hyundai Auto Canada Corp. or there is another link that leads to it at: https://www.hyundaicanada.com/en/mobile-and-audio/blue-link